# Me too! My two year old daughter want to drink and eat everything I do!

Tags: toddler, social-development

I have a lovely 28 month old daughter who talks and walks very well for her age. Currently she is in the phase that she wants to have *everything* I or my wife grabs out of the fridge or storage. If I grab water, she wants water, if I grab a coke, she wants it too. I do not believe at that time she is *actually* thirsty but just wants it "*because*".

How should I deal with this behavior? Should I discourage it by simply stating that she wants it because I have it? Should I ignore her? Should I give her simply the same as I have at that moment?

Comment: Well, don't drink soda... or liquor... and just roll with it. This sounds awesome compared to all the horrors parents typically face

Comment: There is a real benefit to this: she isn't fussy about food. I was terribly fussy as a kid; there were all sorts of things I wouldn't eat and it led to terrible fights with my parents (who were of the view that you ate what you were given). But if you want your daughter to eat her greens, all you have to do is let her see you eating yours. Magic!

Answer (score 3):

I allow it. Mostly.

This has the side benefit making me more mindful of my choices. ie I'm much more likely now to prep a meal together rather than grabbing a coke and a bag of chips.

Where I do still choose things I would not give a toddler I make substitutions but try to preserve some element of sameness. If I drink a coke out of a can I might put juice in a metal water bottle. If I eat whitish chips out of a bag I might provide whitish crackers in a ziplock.

Waste might be obnoxious; if she says she wants a sandwich like yours but only takes one bite. I solve this by not being squeamish about sharing food and taking the toddler's potion out of what I make for myself. If she wants more you make more for both of you, if she doesn't you finish her part.

I can see this becoming a problem if you want her to live in a way very different than you want to. If say she is being raised with a religious or medical diet you can't or won't adopt; I don't have any help to offer there. Otherwise I would think her being on board with learning your way of eating is a big win.

Comment: *This has the side benefit making me more mindful of my choices. ie I'm much more likely now to prep a meal together rather than grabbing a coke and a bag of chips.*

Yes I have noticed myself doing that!

It is more that it is annoying that she wants something as soon as I take something, for instance after I have just returned from home.

Comment: Why is that so strange? You get some and take a snack, of course she wants it too.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good way to get her to eat and drink what you want her to.  Just give her small portions.

I dated a girl and her 4 year old would always want to eat what I was and sit on my lap.  I was eating a spicy hot burrito and I thought I will show him.  He spit it out on the plate.  When I finished his mom said you know you just ate the piece he spit out.